# Uninstalling and Reinstalling SharePoint 2019

Tags: 2019, uninstallation

We currently have a dev environment that includes one App server and one WFE. It wasn't completely set up right from the beginning and having major issues installing Handshake. The decision was made to reinstall and start from scratch. Something as of yet I've never done.

What are best practices here? Should I just uninstall all SP components from both virtual boxes and reinstall or do they need to be wiped completely?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to create new virtual machines. But it is unlikely the *installation* is the issue, just the post-configuration (farm configuration) which can often be adjusted in many ways. I would suggest just addressing the farm configuration, if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have tried to address those issues and the environment works fine from a SharePoint perspective. But we are trying to install and configure the software Handshake and have repeatedly come across issue after issue. So the general consensus since it is such a small dev environment was to just blow it away and start from scratch